# Project has no project.properties file. Changing android project path

Tags: android, eclipse

I changed the folder my android app was in and re-inported it. Then I got the error:

```
Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one. Wakeify - Spotify Alarm - Plus      Unknown Android Target Problem
```

`Android Tools - Fix Project Properties` does not fix this problem. When I go onto the project properties the Path and Location is listed as the old path! I changed the path so I don't understand why it's referencing the old path in the properties. I deleted the old project before re-importing it.

How do I get eclipse to recognise my project in it's new path exactly as it was before except the new path? I have no choice but to use a new path since ndk-build wants a path with no spaces.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project -> Refactor -> Rename -> Change the name to the folder name.

No idea why eclipse needed me to do that but that was the solution.